# How to check the Index of a map in SASS?

Tags: sass

My map contains properties and within each property a value, however I need to check if the property and value is in this list, however I am getting the following `error`:

```
"message": "The color correct does not exist!"
```

Here's my code:

```
$default-color-type-list: 'border-color', 'background-color', 'color';
$default-color-name-list: (
    'cream-1': #FAFAFA,
    'cream-2': #EFEFEF,
    'correct': #02C22B,
    'dark-blue-1': #3897F0,
    'dark-grey-2': #999999,
    'incorrect': #EE2D3E,
    'transparent': transparent,
    'white': white,
);

@mixin getColor($color-name, $color-type) {
    @debug $default-color-name-list;
    @if not index($default-color-name-list, $color-name) {
        @error 'The color #{$color-name} does not exist!';
    }

    @if not index($default-color-type-list, $color-type) {
        @error 'The color type #{color-name} does not exist!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a sass list it's a sass map.

To check if the key exists in map:

```
map-has-key($default-color-name-list, cream-1)
```

And in your case

```
@mixin getColor($color-name, $color-type) {        
    @if not map-has-key($default-color-name-list, $color-name) {
        @error 'The color #{$color-name} does exist!';
    } 

    @if not index($default-color-type-list, $color-type) {
        @error 'The color type #{color-name} does not exist!';
    }
}
```

Comment: `$default-color-name-list` is a `map`, and `$default-color-type-list` is a `list`, not this? Taking this into consideration, your second `if` is wrong.

Comment: Put it the same so I give you score: `@mixin getColor ($ color-name, $ color-property-type) {
    @if not map-has-key ($ default-color-name-map, $ color-name) {
        @error 'The color # {$ color-name} does not exist!';
    } @else if not index ($ default-color-property-type-list, $ color-property-type) {
        @error 'The color type # {color-type} does not exist!';
    } @else {
        $ color-value: map-get ($ default-color-name-map, $ color-name);
        # {$ color-property-type}: # {$ color-value}! important;
    }
}`